# asp.net how to change color of asp:panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I'm trying to change the (back)color of a `panel` in my web application to signal a modal change. I'm using an asp.net WebForm project, with VS Express 2013 for Web. I have a web application with multiple pages, and one of these pages contains a set of three nested panels:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ManageTemplatesPanel" runat="server" style="border-radius:3px" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="White" Height="1415px" Width="930px" ScrollBars="None" BorderWidth="1px">
<asp:Panel ID="BigInsetGrayPanel" runat="server" style="border-radius:3px" BackColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="1275px" Width="910px" >
<asp:Panel ID="SelectClientsWhiteInsetPanel" runat="server" style="margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;border-radius:3px" BackColor="White" Height="465px" BorderStyle="None">
```

Inside each panel there are many controls - text boxes, gridviews, buttons, etc.
Then there is a set of closing tags for the panels.

I have a `CheckBoxList` control with three checkboxes inside:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="IncludeCheckBoxList" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderStyle="None" CssClass="cssIncludeCheckBoxList" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" Height="28px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="IncludeCheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Sent Client List</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Notification Time</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Message</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This is nested inside the "ManageTemplatesPanel". I have created a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler named `IncludeCheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged`. Here is the code:

```
protected void IncludeCheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItemCollection items = IncludeCheckBoxList.Items;
    foreach (ListItem item in items)
    {
        string section = item.Value;
        bool itemChecked = item.Selected;

        if (0 == String.Compare(section, "Sent Client List", true))
            UpdateSentClientSection(itemChecked);
        else if (0 == String.Compare(section, "Notification Time", true))
            UpdateNotificationTimeSection(itemChecked);
        else if (0 == String.Compare(section, "Message", true))
            UpdateMessageSection(itemChecked);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `UpdateSentClientSection`:

```
private void UpdateSentClientSection(bool itemChecked)
{
    if (itemChecked)
        MessageWhiteInsetPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    else
        MessageWhiteInsetPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
}
```

I've searched and several blogs recommend changing the backcolor of a panel in this fashion - but I can't get it to work. Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Update - for some reason the original post didn't contain my panel and CheckBoxList definitions:

Comment: It's already done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to modify an element during an event from the server-side you'll have to use an ajax panel and call ajaxpanel.update() in your method UpdateSentClientSection.

See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: An UpdatePanel (as I understand it) is used to keep a page or portion of a page from flashing due to a post back. How does this help me?

Comment: This will help you because you would have to post again the page to make the change appears of the color. Since the update panel will only update the section, it will be visible directly for the user.